# Solution for 'Selected' CSS Anti-Pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm looking at some of our code and there are lots of instances of the following :

```
link_to t('.projects'), projects_path, :class => params[:controller] == "projects" ? "selected" : ""
```

The purpose of this is to alter the styling of a link/tab/etc to indicate that the current page corresponds to that link. This pattern seems overly brittle and like there should be a better way. Anyone know of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would minimize the logic present in your view. In this case, move your conditional class attribute functionality into a helper class.

In order to make your code less brittle, you can use "controller_name" instead of params[:controller] to compare against your string. This would prevent a possible override from a user passing a "controller" variable.

This function will return either nil, or "selected" based on the argument passed matching the controller_name:

```
def conditional_select(user_controller_name)
  "selected" if controller_name == user_controller_name
end

link_to t('.projects'), projects_path, :class => conditional_select("projects")
```

This allows for code reuse in other links, and easier testing. It also partitions functionality, leaving the link_to to worry about the link, and the "conditional_select" to worry about building the class attribute value.